# Vector space of meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_1,...,z_r  \in \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})  $ be different complex numbers (which is $\mathbb{C}\cup{\infty} $) (or Riemann-sphere).

And let $m_1,...,m_r \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$

Let $V$ be the space of meromorphic function of $ \mathbb{P}^{1}\left(\mathbb{C}\right) $ which are holomorphic on $ \mathbb{P}^{1}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)\setminus\left\{ z_{1},...,z_{r}\right\}  $ and satisfies $ \text{ord}_{z=z_{i}}\left(f\right)\geq-m_{i} $ for all $1\leq i \leq r $.

Im supposed to find the dimension of the vector space $ V $. Im not sure how to do it, and also, Im not sure what function here is the unity and zero of the vector space. I guess its a manner of definition - is holomorphic function also considered to be meromorphic? Or only functions wich have actual poles consideres meromorphic? (If its the latter, not sure what would be the zero of the vector space).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ has a pole of order at most $m$ at $z=a \in \Bbb C$ then the Laurent series at $z=a$ has only entries with exponent $\ge -m$, i.e.
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{n=-m}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n = P_a\left(\frac{1}{z-a}\right) + g_a(z)
$$
in a neighborhood of $z=a$, where $P_a$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m$ without constant coefficient, and $g_a$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z=a$. $P_a\left(\frac{1}{z-a}\right)$ is the so-called “principal part“ of $f$ at the pole.

Similarly, if $f$ has a pole of order at most $m$ at $z=\infty$ then the Laurent series at $\infty$ has only entries with exponent $\le m$, i.e.
$$
  f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^m a_n z^n = g_\infty(z) + P_\infty(z)
$$
in a neighborhood of $z=a$, where $P_\infty$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m$ without constant coefficient, and $g_\infty$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z=\infty$ with a removable singularity at $\infty$. Again $P_\infty$ is called principal part of $f$ at the pole at infinity.

Now, if $f \in V$ and all $z_j$ are finite then
$$
 g(z) = f(z) - \sum_{j=1}^r P_{z_j}\left(\frac{1}{z-z_j}\right)
$$
has removable singularities at each $z_j$ and at $\infty$. It follows from Liouville's theorem that $g$ is constant, so that
$$ \tag{*}
 f(z) = c + \sum_{j=1}^r P_{z_j}\left(\frac{1}{z-z_j}\right) \, .
$$
If $z_r = \infty$ then the same argumentation shows that
$$ \tag{**}
 f(z) = c + \sum_{j=1}^{r-1} P_{z_j}\left(\frac{1}{z-z_j}\right) + P\infty(z)\, .
$$
Conversely, if we choose $P_{z_j}$ as polynomials of degree $\le m_j$ then the functions defined by $(*)$ or $(**)$ are in $V$.

It follows that the constant function $f_1(z) \equiv 1$ together with the functions
$$
 \frac{1}{(z-z_j)^k} \, , 1 \le k \le m_j \, , 1 \le j \le r
$$
form a vector basis for $V$ (with obvious modification if $z_r = \infty$). The dimension is therefore $\dim V = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^r m_j$.

The zero element of $V$ is the function $f_0(z) \equiv 0$: It is holomorphic in $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ and therefore also meromorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: wlog assume that $z_i\ne\infty$ for all $i$. Then note that the map $f\mapsto fg$ where $g(z)=\prod_{i=1}^r(z-z_i)^{m_i}$ yields an isomorphism $V\xrightarrow{\sim}W$ where $W$ is the vector space of those functions $h$ which are holomorphic on $\Bbb C$ and have a pole of order at most $\sum_i m_i$ at $\infty$, i.e. $\operatorname{ord}_{\infty}h\geq-\sum_{i}m_i$. Now what is another way to describe $W$?

Note that if you want to check your answer that this is a special case of the Rieman-Roch theorem.

Comment: W must be the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $m_1+...+m_r $, so that the answer for the dimension is $m_1+...+m_r+1$?  (Since a polynomial is either constant or has a negative order at $\infty $ and this order is the degree of the polynomial. Also, it has to be a polynomial since those funcions are rational functions). But how is that not a loss of generality? as I see it if one of the poles is at $\infty $ then we get another dimension (if its $z_1 $ the dimension would be $m_2+..+m_r+1-m_1 $

Comment: You are right about $W$ and its dimension. To see why we may assume $z_i\ne\infty$ note that in $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$ 'everything looks the same': The group of automorphisms (the Möbius transformations) of $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$ acts transitively on $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$. Thus if one point is $\infty$ then we can choose any $a\in \Bbb C\setminus\{z_1,\dots,z_r\}$ and an automorphism $\phi$ of $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$ such that $\phi(a)=\infty$. Then using the map $f\mapsto f\circ \phi^{-1}$ we may consider the points $\phi(z_1),\dots,\phi(z_r)$ instead of $z_1,\dots,z_r$ and none of them is $\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

Holomorphic functions are meromorphic (in fact, the field of meromorphic functions is the fraction field of the holomorphic functions). Your zero function is the functions constantly equal to zero. You don't need a unit in a vector space, but in any case you can take as unit the function constantly equal to one.

Anyway, since your space $M_{\geq-m}$ contain all holomorphic functions, it's infinite dimensional (notice the polinomials is a infinite dimensional subspace). Im sure that there is an easy way to prove it has a basis of cardinality $c$, but this is what I thought. Your space is separable so it must have dimension $\leq c$.
Now, consider the space $H(K)$ of holomorphic functions over a given conpact set $K \subseteq \Bbb C$. This is a Banach separable space with the supremum norm and, therefore, it must have a basis of cardinality $c$. The restriction function $r :M_{\geq-m} \rightarrow H(K)$ is well defined (as long as $0$ is not a singularity of $f \in M_{\geq-m}$....) and is a suryection so
$$c\geq dim(M_{\geq-m})\geq dim(H(K))=c$$
Again, there must be an easier way. Im not even sure if what I said is completely correct (hope it is).

Comment: This is not correct because the degree of the polynomials is limited by the condition $\text{ord}_{z=z_{i}}\left(f\right)\geq-m_{i}$ for $z_i = \infty$.